# What do I get when I divide the area containing the individuals by the mean of the binomial distribution of individuals?

Tags: probability

I am exploring ideas for my PhD in Plant Epidemiology, I know that the area of a rectangle is:

$area=bh$, where b is base and h is height, and the mean of the binomial distribution is $E[X]=np$ where n is the number of individuals and p is the probability of an individual being "positive".

When I use the equation $area/E[X]$, what does this represent in the real world? Basically, does this equation even make sense?

Thank you for any assistance you can provide!

Comment: Is there is some link between the area and the n individuals? Presuming these n individuals are spread over the area bh, then $\frac{E[X]}{bh}$ would be an expected density of "positive" individuals, with units of individuals per metre-squared (or similar).

Your quantity of $\frac{bh}{E[X]}$ would then be the average area per individual - if it's high then the positive individuals are more widely spaced out.

Comment: From what I've calculated, $\frac{E[X]}{bh}$ gives the density of the total area that is infected. Whereas $\frac{bh}{E[X]}$ I don't understand clearly, but I can understand your reasoning, the higher it is, the more spread out positive individuals are.